# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.http.get')

Tags: node.js, angular, mongodb

Can somebody PLEASE tell me what I'm doing wrong here :

I'm sorry, I feel like I'm losing my mind for 30 minutes.

```
getChartData() {
  this.http
    .get('http://localhost:3001/transactions/' + sessionStorage.getItem('id'))
    .toPromise()
    .then((data: any) => {
      this.data = data;
    });
}
```

```
<button (click)="getChartData()">click</button>
```

Error :

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.http.get')
```

Comment: Can you share more code? What you have in `constructor`, `module`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to return something from your function. With your current code example, If you hover your mouse over the function name, you'll see it says `void`.

Also, I recommend using `observables` rather than `promises`, Angular uses heavily

```js
getChartData() {
   // return the HTTP response
   return this.http.get( 
     'http://localhost:3001/transactions/' 
       + sessionStorage.getItem('id'))
}
```

Then simply, subscribe to it to get the response back

```js
someFunction() {
   this.service.getChartData().subscribe((response) => console.log(response))
}
```